# Python requests: Passing multiple client certificates to session.cert

Tags: python, session, ssl, python-requests

I'm writting a Flask app that connects to external soap service that uses TLS v1.2.
I'm using Python 2.7 and requests library in version 2.18.1.

I've contacted server owner and he told me that I need to include multiple client certificates in TLS connection. It's a chain of 3 certificates which I have in separate .pem files. (root + indermediate + my client certificate).
Server won't let me in if I would have just the last one.

I've tested this with SoapUI and Wireshark and it's true. I receive a response only when I provide the whole chain of 3 certificates.
I get an error from the server when passing just my client certificate.

From [requests documentation](http://3.python-requests.org/_modules/requests/sessions/) you can read that as client certificate you can pass just one cert using:

```
session = requests.session()
session.cert = ('/path/client_cert.pem', '/path/private_key.pem')
response = session.post(SERVICE_URL, data=XML_CONTENT, headers=HEADERS)
```

I get an error even if my "client_cert.pem" file is a bundle of 3 certificates (just like you do it in session.verify with CA certs). I can see on Wireshark that only the first one is used in TLS connection.

Is there any way to include multiple certificates TLS connection in Python's requests library?

Maybe I should use different library or override some of it's code?

Comment: From the documentation the only plausible way seem to be using a single file for the 3 certificates, but if this does not work it's probably unsupported. Consider opening an issue on [`requests` issue tracker](https://github.com/psf/requests/issues).

Comment: The order in client_cert.pem should be leaf + chain certificates. There should be no root certificate given. Works perfectly for me this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got it!

I had some legacy library versions installed.

It seems that this issue was [fixed by requests library developers](https://github.com/urllib3/urllib3/issues/1060) in version 1.23. I also had to update urllib3.

My current **requirements.txt** is:

```
requests==2.22.0
urllib3==1.25.2 # compatible with requests 2.22
```

For following spec everything works perfecly. I've checked TLS connection on Wireshark. All certificates from "client_cert.pem" chain are passed.

If you'll have problems like this in the future remember to check if your requests and urllib3 library versions are compatible.

Thank you guys!